# zsh vs bash difference in for loop, what is the zsh way?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Suppose there is a simple script.

```
for file in `hadoop classpath | tr ':' ' ' | sort | uniq`; do echo $file; done
```

and the original output of `hadoop classpath`  looks like this (the list of folders where to look for the jars):

```
zsh %> hadoop classpath  
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
```

If I run the above script in Bourne shell, the results will be like this (which will give the unique list of all jars contained in the specified classpath):

```
bash-4.1$  for file in `hadoop classpath | tr ':' ' ' | sort | uniq`; do echo $file; done
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar
...
```

In zsh, however, I still get:

```
zsh %> for file in `hadoop classpath | tr ':' ' ' | sort | uniq`; do echo $file; done        
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*
/usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
```

(I.e. nothing more than the folders from the classpath).

For the sake of curiosity, what would be the way to convert the list of directories into the sorted list of files in zsh?

The system in question is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5.

Comment: In general, using for loops this way in bash is frowned on (though since you explicitly want string-splitting and glob expansion, your use case may be an exception); see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: have you noticed that the whole `| sort | uniq` thing is useless since `sort` sorts lines but the `tr` output is still on a single one?  if you wanted to sort the `hadoop classpath` output the pipeline would have to be `hadoop classpath | tr ':' '\n' | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike Bourne shell, zsh does not perform filename generation after expanding a parameter. I.e. `$x` means exactly what it says, the value of the variable `x` passed on as one argument without splitting or filename expansion. To force whitespace splitting, use `${=x}` or invoke `setopt sh_word_split`. To force filename expansion, use `${~x}` or invoke `setopt glob_subst`. To prevent zsh from complaining when a directory contains no files, use the `(N)` modifier that sets the `NULL_GLOB` option for the duration of the pattern.

Combining all these results in:

```
classpath=$(hadoop classpath | tr ':' ' ' | sort | uniq)
for file in ${=~classpath}(N); do
  echo $file
done
```

Note that `sort | uniq` can be shortened to `sort -u` if you're using GNU sort (the default on Linux).

Comment: Thanks for the great tips, though it's still not exactly the same: this script produces the list of blocks of filenames instead of a sorted list of files like bash did.

Comment: @Ashalynd I think I see the problem. I've now amended the answer to produce a list of individual entries rather than a list of expanded chunks.

Comment: cool, that works! one small thing though: if there happens to be no files in one of these folders (like is the case of /usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar) then the shell complains: no matches found: /usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar and outputs nothing at all. So the ideal would be to skip the folders with no files, but I guess I am asking for too much :)

Comment: @Ashalynd Ah, yes, I've amended the answer to fix this using the `(N)` modifier on the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Store the output on a variable first:

```
t=$(hadoop classpath | tr ':' ' ' | sort | uniq)
```

(`$()` is preferred over backticks.)

Then run the loop with `${~var}` format as suggested by [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24756789/445221)

```
for file in ${~t}; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: If I try to run it from shell, zsh says "Bad assignment" about the line when t is set up. If I try to run it from script, it says "Bad substitution"  about the ${~t} part.

Comment: ah sorry, my bad, I had to specify zsh as in the beginning of the script. Still, no luck because it says: no matches found: /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/* /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/* /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/* /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/* /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/* /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/* /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/* /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/* /usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar

Answer (score 0):

a "zsh-native" equivalent of

```
$(hadoop classpath | tr ':' '\n' | sort | uniq)
```

is

```
${(s/:/ou)$(hadoop classpath)}
```

the whole thing is a parameter expansion `${...}`: you can use parameter expansion on more things than just parameter names, to make use of parameter expansion flags without naming the values you want to process.  in this case, we apply some parameter flags to the result of `$(hadoop classpath)`, they're:

- `s/:/` - split the expansion into multiple words on the `:` delimiters
- `o` - sort the resulting words in ascending order
- `u` - expand only the first occurrence of each unique word

then you have the issue of `GLOB_SUBST`: zsh does not perform globbing on parameter expansions by default.  you can change this globally with `setopt GLOB_SUBST`, or for a particular expansion using the `${~spec}` form:

```
for f in ${(s/:/ou)$(hadoop classpath)}; do echo $~f; done
```

alternatively, you could enable `GLOB_SUBST` on the expansion you're looping over:

```
for f in ${(s/:/ou)~$(hadoop classpath)}; do echo $f; done
```

and realize that the whole loop is superfluous:

```
print -l ${(s/:/ou)~$(hadoop classpath)}
```

one more thing: i suspect you only used `sort` as a crutch for `uniq`.  you don't need the `o` parameter expansion flag to achieve only one copy of each pathname, `u` will cope without sorting.